# Inserting value based on any condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
declare @varID as INT = 2

insert into table1
(
ID
,varName
)
select
ID
,**#####**
from table2
```

I want value of `varName` based on `@varID`. How can I do that?

What should be in place of **#####**?

Statement that replicate `IF @varname = 2 then 'P' else 'I'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. Just mention the variable in the SELECT clause. Like this.

```sql
declare @varID as INT = 2

insert into table1 (ID ,varName)
select  ID, 
        CASE WHEN @varID = 2 THEN 'P' ELSE 'I' END
from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END statement like below

```
declare @varID as INT = 2

insert into table1
(
ID
,varName
)
select
ID
,CASE WHEN @varID=2 THEN 'P' ELSE 'I' END
from table2
```